# Chip to hold reset pin low until power rail is stable?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, voltage, sensor

I remember using one a while ago but can't remember what they are called. Need to verify the power rail before using it to power my system.

Comment: Lack of original research. One google search revealed several ICs to choose from.

Comment: I tried to do research, but I had forgotten the name so came up empty.

Comment: "Reset IC" gave plenty of results.

Comment: I am so sorry that you had better luck on google then I did. I asked the question, got what I was after, done now.

Comment: Okay! Good for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for [Reset and Supervisory ICs](http://www.st.com/en/reset-and-supervisor-ics.html).